# re-install purchased apps?

Tags: release-hera

I bought the app Eddy, but needed to re-install eOS, however when I go back to Eddy it is only allowing another purchase as an option. Can anyone advise how (to a noob with linux) I can restore this purchase?

Thanks

Comment: You don't really need to purchase anything from App Center. It's an optional donation that you may wanna make to the developer. If you're not feeling like it, you can simply click on the drop-down next to the "purchase" and change price to 0 to install the app for free.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to. Just choose 0 to pay 0 for the app and then you will be able to install it.

Eventually if you are familiar with the terminal, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install eddy
```

Comment: Cool thanks much!

Comment: hmmm, just tried that and I get "Unable to locate package eddy" ??

Comment: Install it from App Center. Change price to 0 and install.

Comment: Here is the link which may help https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/eddy-install-debian-packages-elementary/

Comment: thanks - got it done!